# Twitter Application Loading How do I do the fluttering application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make the application that we saw when the first twitter application opened in flutter. How can I show the animation in my application and show my first page?

visit: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/assets/loading-screen-01.gif ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you clear, you are trying to build Splash Screens 
For do this in native part directly, you can reference this https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-2019-real-splash-screens-tutorial-16078660c7a1 
,this document also contain youtube video

The following Flutter plugin can help you also 
https://github.com/KarimMohamed2005/SplashScreenFlutterPackage 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_splash_screen 
https://pub.dev/packages/animated_splash 
https://github.com/MeshkaniMohammad/custom_splash_screen

With example of https://github.com/KarimMohamed2005/SplashScreenFlutterPackage 
You can set a timer. full code listed below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SplashScreen(
      seconds: 14,
      navigateAfterSeconds: new AfterSplash(),
      title: new Text('Welcome In SplashScreen',
      style: new TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 20.0
      ),),
      image: new Image.network('https://i.imgur.com/TyCSG9A.png'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
      photoSize: 100.0,
      onClick: ()=>print("Flutter Egypt"),
      loaderColor: Colors.red
    );
  }
}

class AfterSplash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Welcome In SplashScreen Package"),
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text("Done!",
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 30.0
        ),),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```